# Do hot questions conserve their heat after migration?

Tags: support, hot-questions, migrated-questions

Do hot questions that get migrated stay hot in their newly found home, or does migration trigger a reset of the hotness calculation and an instant cooldown?

Answer (score 4):

The hotness score is not tied to the question directly.

That score is calculated every few minutes to determine what questions will appear [here](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot), and it is calculated "from scratch" every time, not taking previous score as base for anything.

So when a question is migrated, when the hotness score recalculates, it might give high enough score to the question on its new site, if it has enough score/answers. But keep in mind that each site has a special "negative factor", which affects the chance of a question from that site to appear in the HNQ.

Bottom line: even if the question will have exact amount of score, answers, and answers score, it might not be "enough" when on the other site. But if it does, nothing else will stop it from appearing as HNQ.

Comment: Hmm, I thought that hotness was related to the rate of views, votes, answers, and age?

Comment: @gerrit views are not part of the formula at all, lots of views are the **result** of a question becoming HNQ. Age is the most critical factor, followed by amount of answers, question score, and sum of score for all answers. Also note I use "score" not votes, i.e. question might have 60 upvotes but score of 1, if it also has 59 downvotes. And for the hotness formula, only the score of 1 matters. :-)