# Reset a question's age for the purposes of Hot Network Questions if it gets migrated

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions, migrated-questions

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/215861/98028) was asked on Movies & TV, and was later migrated to Science Fiction & Fantasy. It got answered there and hit Hot Network Questions about an hour later (see [timeline](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/215861/timeline)).

The problem I have with that is that while it technically *does* meet the "8 hours old" criterion, the majority of those hours *weren't* on the migration target (SFF). In that case, the migration target's folks didn't have the full amount of time to review the question and take whatever action that may have been needed.

That's relatively unharmful in this specific case (although it does promote a zero-research question, despite it being well-written), but I'm more worried about what could happen with more touchy subjects, such as politics, religion, and the like.

Even though users migrating questions are *supposed* to make sure that they're on-topic for the target site ("*don't migrate crap*")<sup>1</sup>, it would **still feel sane (and normal) if the target site's community gets enough time to review it before the question hits HNQ**, which is the whole point of the 8-hour delay, I think. A question can very well be on-topic and neatly written, yet still be controversial enough to spark HNQ drama.

Therefore, I suggest that the "8 hours old" criteria becomes "8 hours old on the site it's currently on". In other words, if a question gets migrated, reset the question's "age" calculated for the purposes of this criterion.

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319699/) is highly related but isn't a feature-request, plus it was asked before the March revamp of HNQ.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Furthermore, if I'm reading [the FAQ post on migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/398063) right, the target site has little (to no) say *before* the thing gets migrated. I imagine some checking is done by the mods/migration-voters prior to the act, but that doesn't sound enough of a failsafe in that case.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

So there is a minimum of 8 hours before the question goes on HNQ, and you are saying that when the question gets migrated to a new site, it should have to go through the entire 8 hours again, for a total of 16 hours minimum on Stack Exchange, plus whatever time it spent on the first site before getting migrated.

Instead of making it go through the entire 8 hours all over again (which is what questions have to go through when they appear from scratch), how about a compromise between the current 0 hours and the 8 hours that you are proposing: For example 4 hours on the new site since it already had 8 hours (or probably much more) on the previous site?

Comment: The purpose of the delay is to give the community time to review the question. If it’s off-topic on the original site and it took 8 hours to get migrated (which doesn’t even allow everyone the potential to see it because half the world is sleeping or working for those 8 hours) why shouldn’t the receiving site get the same amount of time? The sending site’s community isn’t necessarily aware of the receiving site’s standards and conventions.